# Different ways to order tiles

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am looking for some references that generalize the question "how many different ways we have to order $n$ items in a row" to a multi-dimensional setting.
Something like: Assume that there are $n$ (2-dimensional) squares of the same length. What is the number of different (2-dimensional) patterns that can be made using those $n$ squares placing them on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ where every tile is touching at least one other tile?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on how the tiles are arranged? This is probably the most important question. You might be looking for polyominoes, Young diagrams, or other families of shapes comprised of squares...

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are no restrictions.. 
I am not familiar with polyominoes and Young diagrams, I will look it up!
Thanks!

Comment: If there are $n$ squares, and no restrictions on where you put them, then there is an uncountably infinite number of patterns, even if $n=2$, right? You could have the two squares of, let's say, side length one, with $x$ amount of their edges in common, where $x$ is any real number from zero to one.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that you can put them anywhere. Perhaps I misunderstood. Of course you cal put them next to each other which an entire edge in common, i.e., think of tiles in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Please edit the body of your question to make it unambiguous.